# Connection Error with MongoDB and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Trying to connect my express app with mongodb atlas, but I keep getting this MongodbNetworkError

Server.js file

```
    const express = require("express")
    const mongoose = require("mongoose")
    const dotenv = require("dotenv")

    dotenv.config()

    const app = express()

    mongoose
     .connect(process.env.MONGODB_KEY, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
     })
     .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
     .catch(err => console.error(err))

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

Command Line

```
  [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
  Server running on port 5000
  { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND coolcluster-shard-00-00-wqaqv.mongodb.net coolcluster-shard-00-00- 
  wqaqv.mongodb.net:27017
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: please look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447418/unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-cluster-using-mean-stack

Answer (score 1):

You need to whitelist the IP address of your nodejs server in MongoDB.
After login to the account, Follow the steps

```
Go to IP Whitelist view.
  a)In the Security section of the left navigation, click Network Access. The IP Whitelist tab displays.
  b)Click plus icon Add IP Address.
```

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/#add-whitelist-entries

Comment: I do have an ip address of 0.0.0.0/0 including my current ip address added